# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderation

As we enter the second week of the public beta, we desperately need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image] [image] [image] [image]

NOTE: Welcome Shane as a new arrival! It took us a bit longer than the other candidates to get him online. So, welcome!

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections in several weeks.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Will the election process use some kind of different software, or will it simply be a thread on here?

Comment: It will be different software, either by integrating a voting function directly into the site or an external link. It won't just be another Q&A thread. Voting for moderators is a bit too involved for the Q&A engine to handle impartially and fairly.

Comment: In light of the above, we should perhaps close/lock the moderator election thread and stop advertising that thread on the main site. Of course, congrats to Shane as well.

Comment: @Srikant: Removed that from the system message.  Let's see if others want to lock it before I act on that.

Comment: @Shane. There seems little point leaving the moderator election thread open. I think we should lock it.

Comment: @Rob There is no explicit indication that the thread is locked although I did see that you locked it. Is that normal behavior? For example, for closed questions the indicator [closed] appears next to the question.

Comment: Despite the 'locked' status I find that I can still upvote. Is this expected behavior or a bug?

Comment: @Srikant. Locking is meant to "prevent regular users from taking actions on this post". I've no idea whether that is all actions or whether you are a regular user (given your high rep). I'll ask in the chat room.

Comment: @Rob @Srikant: I changed the subject line to make it more obvious.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Can you please accept my answer? Users are complaining that it is constantly bumping to the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, people, start flagging! ;-)

Comment: Congrats to you and to Rob and csgillespie!